# How do I handle '403 Forbidden' respond with python scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have scraped the url of the picture I want, but I use requests module to download the pic, the server responds 403 Forbidden.

I have tried to capture traffic in chrome F12, there are many JS responses in main page and the url of the picture respond just type of Doc

```
import requests

lines =[
'https://i.hamreus.com/ps4/0-9/9%E5%8F%B7%E6%9D%80%E6%89%8B%E6%B9%9B%E8%93%9D%E4%BB%BB%E5%8A%A1[%E9%AB%98%E6%A1%A5%E7%BE%8E%E7%94%B1%E7%BA%AA]/vol_02/seemh-001-a5f6.jpg.webp?cid=121333&md5=7dHbKv51JwzRC6jjd7p3oQ',
'https://i.hamreus.com/ps4/0-9/9%E5%8F%B7%E6%9D%80%E6%89%8B%E6%B9%9B%E8%93%9D%E4%BB%BB%E5%8A%A1[%E9%AB%98%E6%A1%A5%E7%BE%8E%E7%94%B1%E7%BA%AA]/vol_02/seemh-002-c60d.jpg.webp?cid=121333&md5=7dHbKv51JwzRC6jjd7p3oQ',
'https://i.hamreus.com/ps4/0-9/9%E5%8F%B7%E6%9D%80%E6%89%8B%E6%B9%9B%E8%93%9D%E4%BB%BB%E5%8A%A1[%E9%AB%98%E6%A1%A5%E7%BE%8E%E7%94%B1%E7%BA%AA]/vol_02/seemh-003-4b8a.jpg.webp?cid=121333&md5=7dHbKv51JwzRC6jjd7p3oQ',
'https://i.hamreus.com/ps4/0-9/9%E5%8F%B7%E6%9D%80%E6%89%8B%E6%B9%9B%E8%93%9D%E4%BB%BB%E5%8A%A1[%E9%AB%98%E6%A1%A5%E7%BE%8E%E7%94%B1%E7%BA%AA]/vol_02/seemh-004-87ac.jpg.webp?cid=121333&md5=7dHbKv51JwzRC6jjd7p3oQ',
]

def download_pic(url,s):
    pass
    r = s.get(url,headers = headers)
        with open(url.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] +'.jpg','wb') as fp:
        fp.write(r.content())


def main():
    pass
    s = requests.Session()
    main_url = 'https://www.manhuagui.com/comic/12087/121333.html'
    r = s.get(main_url,headers = headers)
    for each_url in lines:
        download_pic(each_url.strip(r'\n'),s)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can't download the picture I want

Comment: you are blocked, you should have an authentication to see or get the picture. Do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Some websites have a security provision against requests from external sources particularly python files. That is why you are getting the 403 error. You will not be able to use either the `urllib` or `requests` module.

My workaround was I made a call to a shell script from python in which I passed the URL of the image. In the shell script I used `$1` to access the url passed with wget to download the image as such:

Python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([filename, url])
```

Script (.sh)

```
wget $1
```

Comment: I use windows 7 system.

Comment: As mentioned by other user they are likely blocked as I get a 200 response and content just fine. Not saying above isn't useful however if works.

Comment: @Bench sorry, don't know about windows. You could download a WGET command utility application for Windows but that would be too much of a headache